# Conflict with jQuery easing, county and lavalamp plugins?

Tags: jquery, counter, jquery-easing, lavalamp

i am using jQuery easing, county and lavalamp plugins in a site i am working.
the menu which uses lavalamp plugin is not working..
The instantiating code is

```
 $(function() {
        $("#fluidMenuBar").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout", 
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

the error that Firefox shows is this,

```
TypeError: $(...).lavaLamp is not a function
```

while this is so, i placed a time counter which uses county plugin

and the same happened for it,

```
TypeError: $(...).county is not a function
```

but these two plugins work perfectly fine in their own separate demo.html files.

My order of files in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/county.js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/queryLoader.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
```

where script.js is generally where i initialise the plugins.

Also, the jquery.js i have included is jquery-1.10.2.js
but my whole site is behaving strangely without this,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

shouldn't that serve the same purpose as my jquery.js file?

Edit: Just realized lavalamp plugin uses easing.js and county plugin is not working if easing.js is used..
Firefox code:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

Comment: Put script.js after the other scripts as you haven't loaded the other libraries when you are trying to call them

Comment: i did. but still not working.

Comment: You should only use one jQuery library, didn't see you had used 2